# How do I change page content with javascript depending on URL being used?

Tags: javascript, url, dynamic, location

I have a single webpage that is shared on 9 different domains. I want the page to auto detect the URL that is being  used to change the phone number on the page. Example:
I own website1.com, website2.com, etc...
I have 9 different phone numbers that I want displayed for each website. How do I code it in java script to detect the URL and change the phone number? I can program out the function no problem just having trouble with the document.location / location.hostname type of script to detect the url and leave room for say i dont know if the page will be in the root OR in a folder. EX: website1.com/index.htm or website1.com/test/index.htm????

Comment: Why are you doing this on the *client*? The server knows what domain the page is being requested from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = top.location.host;
```

or

```
var url = top.location.hostname;
```

if you do a console.debug to top.location, you will find a lot of useful information

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `window.location` is what you need. Please note that `document.location` is deprecated; please use `window.location`, or `top.location` if you're using a frameset.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp.

Comment: yes i am using frameset so thank you very much for this info! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript:

```
document.domain
```

...?